# A category with two notions of weak equivalence?

Tags: ct.category-theory, model-categories

I have a category with two classes of weak equivalences (neither class is contained in the other, and I believe they actually both form homotopical categories). I'm wondering if this notion exists in the literature. I'd like to combine them into one class to obtain a category with weak equivalences (or a homotopical category). I believe this can be done by taking the smallest class of morphisms which contains both classes and which forms such a subcategory. Is there anywhere I can read about something like this?

Comment: This isn't entirely unlike the model-category-theoretic version of Bousfield localization. If you have a model category $C$, a Bousfield localization of $C$ is a model structure on the underlying category of $C$ with the same cofibrations as the original model structure, but with more weak equivalences. Hirschhorn's book "Model categories and their localizations" is a good reference for those ideas. But in your case, neither class of weak equivalences is contained in the other. I doubt that the mixing operation you describe always extends to an operation on the model structures, unfortunately.

Comment: @A.S. Oh that's fine, I don't have a model structure in mind anyway. Thanks for the reference. I'm wondering if there is any subtle issue that I'm not thinking of that would prevent me from constructing what I want.

Comment: Any collection of arrows in a category will form a (directed) graph, and you can always use the image of this graph under the left adjoint to the forgetful functor ${\bf Cat}\to{\bf Graph}$ to 'complete' it into the smallest subcategory of the original category containing those arrows (up to isomorphism), as discussed e.g. [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/free+category) on the nlab. That being said, you may want to try to form a [double category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/double+category) where horizontal arrows are one type of equivalence and vertical arrows are the other type.

Comment: Perhaps a 2-relative category is the sort of thing you have in mind. Dan Kan and I introduced these here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1102.0186.pdf

Comment: This happens quite often. Bousfield localizations have already been mentioned. At a more elementary level, on topological spaces, you have homotopy equivalencies and weak equivalences. Same with chain complexes.

Comment: @FernandoMuro Right, however in the case of topological spaces, homotopy equivalences are, in particular, weak equivalences. In the example I'm thinking of the two notions of weak equivalence are in a sense orthogonal.